# Depth first search algorithm confusion

Tags: java, list, recursion, hashmap, depth-first-search

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Content {
  public String contentid;
  public String locationid;

  public Content(String n, String l) {
      contentid = n;
      locationid = l;
  }
}
```

Now we have 3 locations with locationid 1,2,3 respectively. Location 1 has 3 contents with contentid 2,3,4 respectively, Location 2 has 3 contents with contentid 1,2,3 respectively, Location 3 has 2 contents with contentid 1,2 repectively. Now I want to find all the combinations all contents of these 3 areas and each area can only select 1 content.

Here is my solution using dfs (recursion).

```
 public static List<List<Content>> dfs(String digits, Map<String, List<Content>> m) {
        List<List<Content>> result = new ArrayList<List<Content>>();
        if(digits.length() == 0){
            return new ArrayList<List<Content>>();
        }
        if(digits.length() == 1){
            return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(m.get(Character.toString(digits.charAt(0)))));
        }
        List<List<Content>> intermediate = dfs(digits.substring(1, digits.length()),m);
        for(Content first : m.get(Character.toString(digits.charAt(0)))){
            for(List<Content> rest : intermediate){
                rest.add(first);
                result.add(rest);
                }
            }
        return result;
    }
```

In main:

```
// key is locationid, and values are list of contents

Map<String, List<Content>> m= new HashMap<>(); 
m.put("1", Arrays.asList("2","3","4"));
m.put("2", Arrays.asList("1","2","3"));
m.put("3", Arrays.asList("1","2"));
List<List<Content>> result=dfs("123",m);
System.out.print(result.size());
```

However, my output is 9 which is wrong, it supposed to be 3x3x2=18. I have been debugging for an hour and cannot find where the problem is.

Comment: what are you trying to calculate? what is area?

Comment: the output is the size of the list which should be 3x3x2=18 elements @DeendayalGarg

Comment: You are printing the size of the top level list. If you check each list inside list has size of 2 which basically accounts to size of 18. instead of "System.out.print(result.size());" in main method, do this .... 

        int count = 0;
        for(List<Content> contents :  result){
            count+=contents.size();
        }
        System.out.print(count);